# how to get only table1.col 1 in the result?

Tags: sql, select

How can I get only `table1.col 1` in the result?

```
select table1.col 1, sum (table1.col 2) as sales
from table 1 
join table 2 
on table 1.col 1 = table2. col1 
where condition 1 
and condition 2
group by table1.col1
having sales > 5
order by sales desc
```

Comment: pls provide some example data and your expected output

Comment: present output:

col 1 col 2
1234 5
5678 4
6789 4
 
Expected output:  
col 1 
1234 
5678 
6789

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `sales` column from the select list. Note however that you'll need to use the expression `sum(table1.col2)` in the `having` and `order by` clauses, since the `sales` alias is no longer available:

```sql
select table1.col 1
from table 1 
join table 2 
on table 1.col 1 = table2. col1 
where condition 1 
and condition 2
group by table1.col1
having sum(table1.col2) > 5
order by sum(table1.col2) desc
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Didnt realize that I can do sum in having clause. Thanks.